# Numeros negativos en bucle for PHP

Tags: php

Necesito mostrar una lista que convierte el rango de 100 a -100 en centígrados y los pase a fahrenheit. El problema consiste en que no muestra los numeros negativos, y en la salida se queda la tabla vacía sin mostrar nada. Sin embargo, cuando quito el signo negativo si sirve y me muestra los numeros del 100 al 0. Como hago para mostrar los números negativos?

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$c = 100;
$f = NULL;
echo '<table border="1">
  <th colspan="3">Conversión Celsius a Fahrenheit</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Celsius</td>
    <td>Fahrenheit</td>
    <td>Incremento de 20</td>
  </tr>';
for ($x=-100; $x>=0 ; $x--) {
echo "<tr><td>$c</td><td>".$f=(($c*9/5)+32)."</td><td>";
echo $f+20;
$c=$c-1; }
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te estás complicando más de lo necesario con esas variables $c y $f?

```
for($x=-100; $x<=100; $x++) {
    echo $x . "°C -> " . ($x*9/5)+32 . "°F" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Produce como salida:

```
-100°C -> -148°F
-99°C -> -146.2°F
-98°C -> -144.4°F
...
-1°C -> 30.2°F
0°C -> 32°F
1°C -> 33.8°F
...
99°C -> 210.2°F
100°C -> 212°F
```

Si lo quieres en orden inverso, cambiar a: `for($x=100; $x>=-100; $x--)`

Creo que tu problema es que no estás formateando correctamente la salida en HTML, estás dejando una columna por fuera y no estás cerrando correctamente cada fila. Por eso la página no te está mostrando todos los resultados.
Intenta con esto:

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1">
  <th colspan="3">Conversión Celsius a Fahrenheit</th>
  <tr>
    <td>Celsius</td>
    <td>Fahrenheit</td>
    <td>Incremento de 20</td>
  </tr>' . PHP_EOL;
for($x=100; $x>=-100; $x--) {
    $f = ($x*9/5) + 32;
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $x . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $f . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $f+20 . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Buenas, es que el programa se sigue ampliando en los proximos ejercicios, y el enunciado obliga a que usemos variables para guardarlas.  Voy a intentar modificar mi codigo con el tuyo a ver si me sale.

Comment: Le comento, no me sirve, es como si no aceptara que haya un $x=-100 en for, he cambiado la variable c por la x, y sigue sin mostrarmelos, le edito con mi codigo:       `for ($x=-100; $x>=0 ; $x++) { echo "<tr><td>$x</td><td>".$f=(($x*9/5)+32)."</td><td>";
echo $f+20;
$x=$x+1; }`

Comment: @Mario Creo que tu problema es que no estas formateando bien la salida html. Añadí más cosas a mi respuesta para ver si te funciona. Como no entiendo tan bien el problema, puedes partir de ahi para generar la salida que desees.

Comment: Ahora sí @aeportugal muchas gracias!!